# Average by day using timestamp

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the following mariadb table. The data is added 3 times per day. I am looking to write a SQL query that would give me the average amount for the day. This way I can say on May 13 'serender' averaged x amt, 'shilta' averaged x amt and 'snowq' averaged x amt.  On May 14th the averages were... and so on for each date.

```
       key | timestamp  | card     |  amt |
-------------------------------------------
|      126 | 1620837006 | serender | 8040 | 
|      127 | 1620837006 | shilta   |  752 |   
|      128 | 1620837006 | snowq    |  308 |   
|      132 | 1620862207 | serender |  846 | 
|      133 | 1620862207 | shilta   |  803 | 
|      134 | 1620862207 | snowq    |  759 |   
|      139 | 1620894616 | serender |  845 |
|      140 | 1620894616 | shilta   |  805 |
|      141 | 1620894616 | snowq    |  759 |   
|      146 | 1620923404 | serender |  869 | 
|      147 | 1620923404 | shilta   |  804 |
|      148 | 1620923404 | snowq    |  759 |   
|      153 | 1620948607 | serender |  755 |
|      154 | 1620948607 | shilta   |  650 |
|      155 | 1620948607 | snowq    |  530 |
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *see* the date then convert it from a Unix timestamp to a date:

```
select date(from_unixtime(timstamp)) as dte, card, avg(amt)
from t
group by dte, card;
```

Comment: wow simple enough i think that's exactly what i needed thanks